# Extracting equations and images from Word

Tags: .net, vb.net, ms-word, extract, equation

Is there a programmatic way to extract equations (and possibly images) from an MS Word document?  I've googled all over, but have yet to find anything that I can sink my teeth into and work from.  If possible, I'd like to be able to do this with VB.NET or C#, but I can pick up enough of any language to hack out a DLL.  Thanks!

**EDIT:** Right now I'm looking at extracting the equations from Word 2003, but if converting it to 2007/Open XML is required, that's fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if any of this will help, but the object model in Word 2000/2003 has an `InlineShapes` collection as part of the `Document` object which represents embedded images and possibly similar objects like equations.

Some VBA code to copy the first item onto the clipboard, which might help you extract them:

```
ThisDocument.InlineShapes.Items(1).Select
Selection.Copy
```

It's accessible in .NET too, [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.inlineshapes(VS.80).aspx).

Answer (score 6):

What Word format are your documents in? If they are in Open XML (file extension .docx) you could use the [Open XML SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=C6E744E5-36E9-45F5-8D8C-331DF206E0D0) available from Microsoft to extract images and embedded content.

An Open XML file is nothing but a zip archive using a special structure. You will find examples in the SDK how to access parts of that zip archive. Actually you could use any zip-capable library to extract the content from the document package.

If the documents still use the older binary format things are a bit more complicated. I think the easiest way would be to convert the documents to the Open XML format. There are several ways to do this:

- Get the free and open [b2xtranslator](http://b2xtranslator.sourceforge.net/) from SourceForge which offers you C# dlls for file conversion.
- Install Microsoft's [Compatibility Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=941b3470-3ae9-4aee-8f43-c6bb74cd1466&displaylang=en) and use the following command line for conversion:

  `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\wordconv.exe" -oice -nme input\_file output_file`

where input_file and output_file must be full path names.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the [Word-to-latex](http://kebrt.webz.cz/programs/word-to-latex/) converter. It requires the .Net framework and although the source isn't opened yet the author does invite questions about this.